# I am having issue with deploying any cloud function. You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project

Tags: google-cloud-functions

This problem begun suddenly. I can`t deploy anything now. Allways same issue.
I use simple example with helloWorld:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// const logger = require("firebase-functions/lib/logger");

exports.helloWorld = functions.region("europe-west3")
    .https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      // logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
      response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
    });
```

And still the same issue.

I have around 15 cloud functions in thi project so far, so dont really know where the issue comes from.... Anyone faced this before?

I deployed same function in another project with sucess...

Comment: *firebaser here* There was a change in Cloud Functions that is causing problems for Firebase and Extensions. Check the answer to the question I linked, where one of our engineers explains and links to the issue on Github.

Comment: This does not solving the issue, settinx instances to 0, 10, 32 or 100 or even 3000 changes nothing with this behaviour. Still getting : This function has failed to deploy and will not work correctly. Please edit and redeploy.
You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project

Comment: I reffer evryone experiencing this issue here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6298